# Center a progress bar vertically

Tags: android

I have an interminate `ProgressBar` inside a `RelativeLayout` along with some other view elements and I'm unable to center the progress bar vertically. I tried `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`, `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`, `android:layout_gravity="center"`, and `android:gravity="center"` but it wouldn't work!

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/swipe">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Random number:"
            android:id="@+id/lbl" 
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rndNum"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbl" 
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Edit**: The progress bar, however, is being centered horizontally.

**Update:** This is how the view is being rendered
[image]

Comment: change android:layout_height="wrap_content" of relative layout to  android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: @IllegalArgument It was `match_parent`, I changed it to `wrap_content` as per IDE's suggestion.

Comment: @BasitSaeed android:layout_height="wrap_content" for relative layout will make your view take as much space as required to fit the content. It will not add white spaces to your progress bar to center it vertically. Alternate approach would be to use Root RelativeLayout and scrollview a child of it

Comment: Set `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to your relative layout.

Comment: Try `android:centerInParent="true"`

Comment: @PankajKumar I tried `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` as I said so in my question, as well. Didn't work.

Comment: @PratikButani Nop! That didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

If you dont wan to set RelativeLayout layout_height to match_parent then take FrameLayout as parent layout of your ScrollView and put you ProgressBar out-side RelativeLayout like below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/swipe">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Random number:"
                    android:id="@+id/lbl"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/rndNum"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbl"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: What happens when and if data exceeds device's height? Would scollbar show as it is placed inside `FrameLayout`?

Comment: Yes obviously please try to put more data in Relative Layout and check.

Answer (score 2):

Its because your `ScrollView` is causing the problem, you can solve it by adding the following line to your `RelativeLayout`,

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:gravity="center"'
```

But I am not sure why you want to vertically center a view inside a `ScrollView` which will be worthless if the content of `ScrollView` is more than the screen size. But this answer will surely serve your current purpose.

Comment: As suspected, it is making everything inside `RelativeLayout` centered.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I ONLY want the `ProgressBar` to be centered vertically (and horizontally), not the entire view.

Comment: @BasitSaeed: But why do you want it vertically centered in a `ScrollView`? any specific requirement? Because anyway while scrolling it will change.

Comment: The ScrollView is there just in case data exceeds the height of the device. ProgressBar should be centered both horizontally and vertically (as the data loads via AsyncTask) for aesthetic reasons. I can place it outside the RelativeLayout if it serves the purpose. I just want to display it during `doInBackground` of `AsyncTask` and that's it.

Comment: Then in this case, I would suggest to keep the `ProgressBar` outside the `ScrollView` which will serve your purpose.

Comment: It should. Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: Nop! Now I have a fatal error that suggests `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` can only have 1 child layout.

Answer (score 0):

use **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** in RelativeLayout to center a view

like

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Comment: I've mentioned it in my question that I tried these avenues and they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use `Framelayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides other answers, notice that if the parent view or parents' parent view or ... of your `progressBar` is `ScrollView`, none of the abovementioned attributes including `layour_gravity`, `gravity` and `center_in_parent` will work. So, you need to put the ProgressBar outside the `ScrollView`.